# Exclusive sums in trees

Tags: algorithm

I have an in-tree in which each node has either one or two parents and is associated with a value.

In *O(N)* time I can find each node's cumulative sum (sum of all values above it in the tree) where the root contains the sum of the whole tree. I can also find a topological sort.

Now I have a set of K nodes and want to find each of these nodes' exclusive sums: their cumulative sum minus the cumulative sums of any of the other k nodes which are above them in the tree.

There's an issue with double-counting, though. If a node N has an ancestor A in the set K and A has an ancestor B in K then the exclusive area of N is only cumsum(N)-cumsum(A), not cumsum(N)-cumsum(A)-cumsum(B).

DFS on the original tree gives the exclusive sums in *O(N)* time in the size of the tree, but this may be unacceptably long since I'll consider many sets of K.

There's probably an *O(|K|^2)* solution, but that becomes prohibitive if K is of only moderate size, and it's not obvious how it would avoid double-counting.

Is there preprocessing I can do to get an *O(|K|)* solution?

Comment: *"all values above it in the tree...the root contains the sum of the whole tree"*: so we picture the root at the bottom "below"? Can you give a concrete example of this graph?

Comment: What do you mean by "in-tree"? Is it actually a tree? If so, how many levels is the tree likely to have? Would `O(k * min(k, levels))` be fast enough?

Comment: When the edges of a tree are directed towards the root, it's called an "in-tree" or anti-arborescence.

Comment: @btilly: The longest path in the tree is probably O(100)-O(1000). The branching factor is relatively low. Does that help?

Comment: From the example with nodes `N`, `A`, and `B` it sounds like you only really need the lowest ancestor of node `N`, `A` that is in the set `K` in order to calculate `N`'s exclusive sum. If this is the case, the question is reduced to efficiently finding the lowest ancestor of a given node where the ancestor is in the set `K`, for each node in `K`, if you calculate all nodes' cumulative sums beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `O(k log(n))` solution that requires `O(n)` additional memory.

Nodes can be divided into parents of branching points, and other. With the root being an honorary parent of a branching point.

For each node, record the following facts.

1. `depth[node]` is the node's depth in the tree.
2. `cumulative_sum[node]` is the cumulative sum at or below the node.
3. `branch_parent[node]` is the next node, possibly itself, that is the parent of a branch.

Then for parents of branching points we also need to record `next_branch_parent` to be the next parent of a branch point up the tree (none if it is the root).

Now the idea is that we do all of our accounting at the branch parents. Which there are at most `log(n)` of up the tree from each of our `K` nodes. Something like this:

```
this_cumulative_sum = {}
accounted_for_sum = {}
for node in (your K nodes, sorted by depth descending):
    if branch_parent[node] not in accounted_for_sum:
        branch_parent[node] = 0
    this_cumulative_sum[node] = cumulative_sum[node] - accounted_for_sum[branch_parent[node]]
    parent = branch_parent[node]
    while parent is not None:
        if parent not in accounted_for_sum:
            accounted_for_sum[parent] = 0
        accounted_for_sum[parent] += this_cumulative_sum[node]
        parent = next_branch_parent[node]
```

The sort is `O(K log(K)) = O(K log(n))`. Figuring out `this_cumulative_sum[node]` is `O(1)` per node. Recording the accounting is `O(log(n))` per node. So all the calculation across all of the nodes is `O(K log(n))`.